# What's the difference between these non and alternative syntax

Tags: php

**1. Alternative Syntax**

```
<?php if ($pager instanceof sfPropelPager): ?>
<?php foreach ($pager->getResults() as $iNo => $item): ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $iNo % 2 == 0 ? "dataRowOdd" : "dataRowEven";?>" style="height: 20px;">
        <td>
            <?php echo "<a href='extData/extView?id={$item->getId()}'></a>" ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item->getDate("d.m.Y");?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**2. Non-alternative syntax?**

```
<?php
  if ($pager instanceof sfPropelPager)
  {
      foreach ($pager->getResults() as $iNo => $item)
      {
          $rowClass = $iNo % 2 == 0 ? 'dataRowOdd' : 'dataRowEven';
          echo "<tr class='$rowClass' style='height: 20px;'>";
          echo "<td> <a href='extData/extView?id={$item->getId()}'>#{$item->getId()}</a> </td>";
          echo "<td> {$item->getDate('d.M.Y')} </td>";
          echo "</tr>";
      }
  }
?>
```

I prefer the 2nd option because it's easier to implement and readable for me. Even though, the outputs are similar. But I couldn't figure out which I should put my coding habit into.

Comment: One is the alternative syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: The first example is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Obviously it is just slightly syntactically different.

Comment: This is just different syntax styles - completely up to you and your team which you find easier to support and maintain. There is no technical advantage.

Comment: Any up/down side for each style? or they're totally similar to each other?

Comment: Always favor readability and maintainability in your coding style.  Use the style you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first **example** your using [Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

**Advantages:**

- They are shorter.
- They are easy to write

**Disadvantages:**

- But i'm not recommending them because when using **alternative syntax** it may lead to some syntax errors. Eg: white space
- Also when it comes to huge code.. you may be find hard to go though
  each statement and find what's wrong.

Also for your second **example** you can change the `echo` part.Because your echoing it always..You can use it like below.

```
$html = '';

if ($pager instanceof sfPropelPager)
  {
      foreach ($pager->getResults() as $iNo => $item)
      {
          $rowClass = $iNo % 2 == 0 ? 'dataRowOdd' : 'dataRowEven';
          $html .= "<tr class='$rowClass' style='height: 20px;'>";
          $html .= "<td> <a href='extData/extView?id={$item->getId()}'>#{$item->getId()}</a> </td>";
          $html .= "<td> {$item->getDate('d.M.Y')} </td>";
          $html .= "</tr>";
      }

      echo $html;
  }
```

Comment: "**For the first example your using short tags:**" I don't see any php short tags (`<?=` or `<?`) on any of the examples.

Comment: @PedroLobito it was a mistake..i read it fast and got it as using php short tags..when you said only i recognized..Thanks! i have updated my answer

Comment: N.P., I just don't see the update reflected on your answer ;)

Comment: @PedroLobito check :)

Answer (score 2):

The **2nd** code looks cleaner and easier to read but I still prefer using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid messing with quotes and semicolons, i.e.:

```
  if ($pager instanceof sfPropelPager)
  {
      foreach ($pager->getResults() as $iNo => $item)
      {
          $rowClass = $iNo % 2 == 0 ? 'dataRowOdd' : 'dataRowEven';
          echo <<< LOL
          <tr class='$rowClass' style='height: 20px;'>
          <td> <a href='extData/extView?id={$item->getId()}'>#{$item->getId()}</a> </td>
          <td> {$item->getDate('d.M.Y')} </td>
          </tr>
LOL;

      }
  }
```

`Heredoc` can be very handy for long blocks of `html` mixed it `php`. Just keep in mind the `heredoc` closing statement (`LOL;`) **must be** in the beginning of the line.

---

> The PHP community is large and diverse, composed of innumerable
>   libraries, frameworks, and components. It is common for PHP developers
>   to choose several of these and combine them into a single project. It
>   is important that PHP code adhere (as close as possible) to a common
>   code style to make it easy for developers to mix and match various
>   libraries for their projects.
>
> The [Framework Interop Group](http://www.php-fig.org/) has proposed and approved a series of
>   style recommendations. Not all of them related to code-style, but
>   those that do are [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md), [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) and [PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md).
>   These recommendations are merely a set of rules that some projects
>   like Drupal, Zend, Symfony, CakePHP, phpBB, AWS SDK, FuelPHP, Lithium,
>   etc are starting to adopt. You can use them for your own projects, or
>   continue to use your own personal style.

---

**RESOURCES:**

http://www.phptherightway.com/#code_style_guide   (definitely check this site!)
http://www.php-fig.org/
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you as a developer to choose which one you like better. You say you prefer the second option, so why not use that.

Comment: Yes I stick to the 2nd one because it's more comfortable to me. But, I don't have slightest clue for any technical or performance reason.

Comment: @choz They are just alternative syntax, nearly no technical or performance differences. Just stick to the second one if it's more comfortable.